# Marklogic distributive constraint

Tags: marklogic

Suppose that we have a constraint named "Title" and our query is as follow:

- Title:dad OR Title:mom

does Marklogic support a distributive formula as follow:

- Title:(dad OR mom)

so they are equivalent.

However, I test it using the following query:

```
search:search("Title:(Medical OR Medicine)",
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <return-results>false</return-results>
      <return-facets>false</return-facets>
      <constraint name="Title">
            <word type="xs:string" facet="false">
              <element ns="http://example.com" name="Title"/> 
            </word>
        </constraint>
    </options>)
```

They are not the same, is there any way in Marklogic to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom constraint where you parse the right-hand side of the constraint yourself and build a query that suites your needs.

Have a look here: https://developer.marklogic.com/try/ninja/page13